# uncaught reference error when sending variable through onclick to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im trying to send a php variable to a javascript function so that i can post it using ajax however i keep receiving the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: "username" is not defined.(Changed where it says username for privacy reasons)
I'm drawing blanks as what the problem could be as it works correctly with previous functions. What is it that i am doing wrong

Ive tried converting the username to a string, as well as weeding out syntax errors but to no avail.

```
   <?php
    foreach($arrlist as $farr){
    $onlineusersquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
    username = '$farr' AND online = '2'");
    $onlineusers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($onlineusersquery);
    if(in_array($farr,$onlineusers)){
    $recipient = (string)$farr;
    print "<span class=openclick style=cursor:pointer;margin- 
   left:2vmax;position:relative; onclick=friendinteract(".$num.")>".$farr." 
   </span></br>";
    print"<div class=friendinteract>";
    print "<span class=message onclick=message(".$num.") style=margin- 
   left:3vmax;cursor:pointer;position:relative;color:#fffff1;>Message</span> 
   </br>";
    print "<span class=chat onclick=chat(".$recipient.") style=margin- 
   left:3vmax;cursor:pointer;position:relative;color:#fffff1;>Chat</span>";
    print"</div>";
    $num++;
     }
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chat(recipient){
    var username = recipient;
    $.post("chat.php", {usernumber: username}, function(result){
     console.log(result)
     });
    }
    </script>
```

i expect the variable to be sent to the function so it can be posted however i receive Uncaught ReferenceError: "username" is not defined

Comment: In your `php` check whether `$recipient` variable has any value or not.

Comment: I can't see anything in your JS logic which would create that error. However, your PHP is probably not generating valid HTML due to the missing and/or mis-matched quotes. Try this: `print '<span class="chat" onclick="chat(\''.$recipient.'\')">Chat</span>';` I'd also suggest moving the inline styling in to an external stylesheet.

Comment: it does it is set to a username in my db and is able to report the username into the error code on inspect

Comment: I wonder what would happen if [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) decided to use your website.

Comment: tried Rory's suggestion still receive the same error

Comment: @Madustmg On what line are you getting the error exactly?

Comment: print "<span class=chat onclick=chat(".$recipient.") style=margin- 
   left:3vmax;cursor:pointer;position:relative;color:#fffff1;>Chat</span>"; is where i am getting the error

Comment: @Madustmg I edited your code removing inline-styles and put the html portion outside php scriptlets, hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery if this does not work

replace span with this below:

```
"<span class='chat' data-user='".$recipient."' style='margin-      left:3vmax;cursor:pointer;position:relative;color:#fffff1;'>Chat</span>";
```

use this in jquery

```
$('.chat').on('click',function(){

    var username= $(this).attr(data-user);

$.post("chat.php", {usernumber: username}, function(result){
 console.log(result)
 });


    });
```